# Design patterns for type-safe integers?

Tags: java, design-patterns, type-safety

I have an application that works with a entities that all have an integer ___ID primary key (e.g. StudentID, CourseID...etc)

I want to add a bit of type safety to the program, so for example a function that takes as input a StudentID, cannot be accidentally passed a CourseID.

First idea that came to my mind is to create simple empty classes like this:

```
public class StudentID extends java.util.Integer {}
public class CourseID extends java.util.Integer {}
```

This doesn't work since `java.util.Integer` is `final` and can't be extended.

Second idea is to have a data class that only holds an integer:

```
public class StudentID {
    private final int id;
    public int get() { return id; }
}
```

Though it would be a lot of boilerplate code.

Third idea is like second idea but to save on boilerplate code by having one base class that defines the get method and empty classes that inherit from it:

```
public abstract class AbstractID {
    private final int id;
    public int get() { return id; }
}

public class StudentID extends AbstractID{};
public class CourseID extends AbstractID{};
```

Are there any other/better known patterns for this problem?

Comment: It's not `java.util.Integer` but `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: I like the second idea, despite some duplicating codes.

Comment: why is this a problem?  Sounds like a solution for an imaginary issue.  If you pass an int that isn't a key, you'll get no rows back.  So what?

Comment: @duffymo - what if the passed int does happen to have a record - but the id passed was ( mistakenly at runtime ) was not intended to fetch that record ? Adding typesafety eliminates these chances.

Comment: Depending upon how extensively the `AbstractID` is used - #3 could be the best way forward IMO. If its just 2 classes that have the ID in them then I will just go with #2 approach.

Comment: @duffymo usually in SQL for example the IDENTITY columns would be independent, so yes it is very likely that there would be a student with ID 201 and a course with ID 201.

Comment: then it's a bug in the code that ought to be fixed.  i think this solution is a waste of time.  a bad idea.

Comment: I also don't really see the problem here. I have worked with large integer-id-based table hierarchies and corresponding Hibernate class hierarchies in the past with no such issue. I think what you need is unit tests to avoid any issue. If you want to further isolate your application from human errors you could introduce random string public identifiers for user facing APIs so the user never sees the integers and you are isolated from id mismatches.

Comment: Just to add to that: regardless of any layer of indirection you use, at some point you have to create the ID object: nothing protects you from creating this object with the wrong value. However, using ORM queries and with good tests, you can convince yourself of the correctness of the internals of your application without complicating the implementation.

Comment: @Giovanni Botta, I do not agree that tests alone are a solution, you can argue the same thing for generics, it's like saying we don't need generics in Java because if you have good tests then they should be able to catch these type errors...

Comment: @Morad I don't think the two things compare really. If you are using integer IDs you still have integer IDs, no matter how you wrap them: when you create the ID you can still mess up the value. My point is that ORM system isolate us already from 95% of these issues and you can take care of the remaining 5% with good tests. Another approach is to use public ids that are random strings instead of integers. That way even if the user enters a bad string, it's highly unlikely to hit the wrong data, they will get no data instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `ID<T>`? If you want to restrict some argument to a function, I think you can do as following:

```
void foo (ID<? extends Student> param);
```